# ListView With three fields

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview

Iam Trying to make a financial application and i want to put a image, a text with the description, and the money in the account, in a listview line.. how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `CustomAdapter` as a subclass of `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`.
Inflate your custom `row.xml` (Which will be your layout for a single row) and then set that `adapter` to the `ListView`.
Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)